How to register resourceResolverFactory with custom resource mapping in aem context?
I have a model class where i inject ResourceresolverFactory and obtain resourceResolver using it to map my link urls. resourceResolver = resourceResolverFactory.getServiceResourceresolver(map);
resourceResolver.map(link);
I am using aemContext to test this class and want to configure the resourceResolverFactory of aemContext with custom resource mapping.
I tried the below snippet of code however it gave me an error.I am not sure how else to configure custom configuration and register the service with aem context
@BeforeEach
public void setUp(AemContext context) {
    // Define custom mappings for the ResourceResolverFactory
    Map<String, Object> resolverConfig = new HashMap<>();
    resolverConfig.put("resource.resolver.mapping", new String[]{
        "/content/:/",
        "/content/dam/:/dam",
        "/etc/map/:/mymap"
    });

    // Register the ResourceResolverFactory with the custom mappings
    context.registerInjectActivateService(ResourceResolverFactory.class, resolverConfig);

    // Optionally, load some test content into the context
    context.load().json("/path/to/test-content.json", "/content");
}

I obtain the following error while trying to use this configuration and running my code
Error image

Do not post code or error messages as image. See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors why.

It’s not possible to instantiate a service from ResourceResolverFactory.class because ResourceResolverFactory is an interface.
There is a constructor for AemContext that takes a map of resource resolver factory props as argument. Try passing your resolverConfig to that.

Would loading etc/map json to the context help in any sort?

You’ll have to try. I’m doubtful the mock ResourceResolverFactory will look for the mappings in /etc/map.
Better to use the AemContext(org.apache.sling.testing.mock.osgi.context.ContextPlugins, java.util.Map<java.lang.String,java.lang.Object>, boolean, org.apache.sling.testing.mock.sling.ResourceResolverType) constructor signature and pass resolverConfig as the second argument.
